# How to listen for realtime updates in Firebase Cloud Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-apps-script, google-cloud-firestore

In the official documentation of Firebase, we can do it with https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen

```
let doc = db.collection('cities').doc('SF');

let observer = doc.onSnapshot(docSnapshot => {
  console.log(`Received doc snapshot: ${docSnapshot}`);
  // ...
}, err => {
  console.log(`Encountered error: ${err}`);
});
```

But how can we do it with Google Apps Script?

Answer (score 0):

To run an Apps Script on a event (like a data update) implies using triggers. Unfortunately, at the moment there are no [Apps Script triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/) supporting Firebase.

However, you can include JavaScript code in the [HTML](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/) file attached to your Apps Script file and deploy it as a [Web App](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web).